# Not able to connect Power Bi Desktop with Dropbox

Tags: excel, api, dropbox, powerbi

I have an excel spreadsheet in Dropbox that I would like to load in the Power Bi Desktop. I am not able to connect Power BI Desktop with Dropbox.

This is what I did-

I created an app in Dropbox and then generated an app token that has access to all the folders in Dropbox.

Then I used the Web Connector in the Power BI Desktop with the v2 API URL

URL: https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download

HTTP Header

Authorization : Bearer api_token

Dropbox-API-Arg : {\"path\": \"/folder/file.xslx\"}"

[image]

Once I click on Ok, I get a 400 Error that says "Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download' (400): Bad Request"

[image]

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you read out the response body? It should contain a more useful error message. Otherwise, looking at what you supplied, two things come to mind: 1) You may not need to escape the `"` in this environment. I.e., in the `Dropbox-API-Arg` header value, try using `"` instead of `\"`. 2) This endpoint requires a POST, but I don't see where that's configured. Are you using GET? If you can't use POST, refer to [the "Content-download endpoints" section](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#formats) for an alternative.

Comment: @Greg I have not specified a GET or a POST in my request.

Comment: If you're not specifying it, it's probably just using GET, which wouldn't be valid. Switch to POST if you can, or use the alternative in the documentation I linked to.